# Fewer rows versus fewer columns

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am currently modeling a table schema for PostgreSQL that has a lot of columns and is intended to hold a lot of rows. I don't know if it is faster to have more columns or to split the data into more rows.

The schema looks like this (shortened):

```
CREATE TABLE child_table (
  PRIMARY KEY(id, position),
  id bigint REFERENCES parent_table(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  position integer,
  account_id bigint REFERENCES accounts(account_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  attribute_1 integer,
  attribute_2 integer,
  attribute_3 integer,
  -- about 60 more columns
);
```

Exactly 10 rows of `child_table` are at maximum related to one row of `parent_table`. The order is given by the value in `position` which ranges from 1 to 10. `parent_table` is intended to hold 650 million rows. With this schema I would end up with 6.5 billion rows in `child_table`.

Is it smart to do this? Or is it better to model it this way so that I only have 650 million rows:

```
CREATE TABLE child_table (
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  id bigint,
  parent_id bigint REFERENCES other_table(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  account_id_1 bigint REFERENCES accounts(account_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  attribute_1_1 integer,
  attribute_1_2 integer,
  attribute_1_3 integer,
  account_id_2 bigint REFERENCES accounts(account_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  attribute_2_1 integer,
  attribute_2_2 integer,
  attribute_2_3 integer,
  -- [...]
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of columns and rows matters less than [*how well they are indexed*](http://www.postgresguide.com/performance/indexes.html).  Indexes drastically reduce the number of rows which need to be searched.  In a well-indexed table, the total number of rows is irrelevant.  If you try to smash 10 rows into one row you'll make indexing much harder.  It will also make writing efficient queries which use those indexes harder.

Postgres has [many different types of indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-types.html) to cover many different types of data and searches.  You can even write your own (though that shouldn't be necessary).

---

> Exactly 10 rows of child_table are at maximum related to one row of parent_table.

Avoid encoding business logic in your schema. Business logic changes all the time, *especially* arbitrary numbers like 10.

---

One thing you might consider is reducing the number of attribute columns, 60 is a lot, *especially if they are actually named `attribute_1`, `attribute_2`, etc*. Instead, if your attributes are not well defined, store them as a single [JSON column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) with keys and values. Postgres' JSON operations are very efficient (provided you use the `jsonb` type) and provide a nice middle ground between a key/value store and a relational database.

Similarly, if any sets of attributes are simple lists (like `address1`, `address2`, `address3`), you can also consider using [Postgres arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html).

---

I can't give better advice than this without specifics.

Comment: If it's "only" attribute_1 to attribue_n `hstore` is probably the better choice because it is more efficient than JSON as long as you don't need hierarchical attributes

Comment: I found some benchmarks of [hstore vs JSON](http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/talks/hstore-dublin-2013.pdf) and hstore is indeed very fast. However, jsonb has since been introduced which, like hstore and unlike json, is stored as a binary format. I wonder how it would do against JSONB.

Comment: I would stay `JSONB` still has a higher overhead than `hstore`

Comment: The `attribute_x` columns have correct names and specified purposes, I just removed them for simplicity so that I don't have to introduce the context (video game statistics with 10 players). Your argument about the changing logic is correct and likely to happen and I will trust the indices then.